# Need Outdoor Application Power Transistors

Tags: power, 12v

I am looking for preferably readily available power transistor technologies that are adequate for high humidity and extreme environmental temperature fluctuation. This is because they will be in a circuit that is mounted on the exterior of a car (in a case of course, but still).

Electrical requirements:
*Low voltage Drop (<100mV)
*0-10A
*12V
Schematic: Positive --> Switching Module --> Load --> Chassis/Ground

These will be for a module that controls loads such as potentially high power lights on the exterior the vehicle.

I was thinking of possibly power p-MOSFETS because of the low voltage drop, but they need to be able to survive these outdoor environments. Do any of you have any ideas.

Comment: this kind of requirement is generally fixed in mechanical design and packaging, not device selection.

Answer (score 2):

There are no special outdoor transistors on the market. Find a transistor which fits your electrical requirements, then solve your environmental needs, probably with conformal coating.

Answer (score 0):

High-side Switch: P-channel MOSFET.

High Ambient Temperature: Be sure to use derating formulas or curves. Ambient could be 50C with sun shining on the box. Maybe 60C in Phoenix.

Temperature Cycling: good stress relief on component leads.

Moisture: conformal coating or encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many parts that will do this.  A quick scan at Digi-Key yielded almost 100 line items that are good at least 25 V and 20 A, in an assortment of packages.  With Rdson as low as 8 milliohm, power dissipation is less than 1 W.  That is good for a 50 degC ambient with no heatsink.

https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOI21357.pdf

Another option is a chassis mount, bolt-down package.  Expensive, but ultra-rugged.

[https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_p-channel_ixtn170p10p_datasheet.pdf.pdf](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_p-channel_ixtn170p10p_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There are MIL sealed ceramic packages, but that's a little bit more extreme, as in "space vacuum in orbit".

Your average epoxy package chip would run fine underwater, if all the connections on the PCB didn't quickly fail due to electrolysis.

The rest of the PCB is much more vulnerable than your MOSFET, so you have to protect the whole thing in a suitable case. Otherwise with enough humidity, pretty much everything can oxidize, electrolyze, and fail: connectors, component pins, solder joints... most electronics are remarkably waterproof when not powered (it is possible to wash boards unless some specific components like unsealed relays forbid it) but as soon as there is power and water, electrolysis will destroy your circuit very quickly... thin IC pins just dissolve...

You can apply conformal coating (waterproof tropicalisation varnish) to the PCB to prevent corrosion and electrolysis. You can also pot it in resin, but that's not ideal for repairs. Some of these resins do not solidify but form a gel, which is removable, so much easier to repair.

You need to think about the enclosure, how cables will go through the wall, if it needs to be watertight or just splashproof... You can use sealed connectors, or sealed cable glands.

If you need cooling then the best is an aluminium enclosure, since it can act as a heat sink and dissipate the heat outside without any vents.